# Using CSS for MToolItem in Eclipse

Tags: css, eclipse, toolbar

I have a reference in my CSS that highlights the MToolBar background when focused.

```
ToolBar:focus {
   background-color: #ffffff;
}
```

Is there any way of using this technique with MToolItem?

I've tried the obvious ways I can think of, such as ToolItem:focus, ToolBar > ToolItem:focus etc.

Grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. The CSS support does not define a 'CSS element provider' for ToolItem so it can't be used as a CSS selector.

Comment: Thank you Greg, then I can give up that lead. Is there any other way to mark the selected item? I haven't been able to add any kind of listener, and it doesn't appear to have a hot-image like a plain ToolBar.

Comment: The underlying code is still just a normal Toolbar but the CSS code doesn't have any support for setting the hot image. You can use the `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler` and `org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.elementProvider` extension points to define handlers for CSS properties. Or maybe use a customized tool bar renderer.

Comment: I cannot get it to work, the make use of controls only and don't handle models. Is there any custom toolbar suited for this purpose out there?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really an answer. I tried to implement the extension like this. But it didn't work for me, is there something I forgot?

```
/*plugin.xml*/
<extension point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.propertyHandler">
    <handler 
        adapter="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.ToolItemElement"
        composite="false"
        handler="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.properties.css2.CSSPropertyBackgroundSWTHandler">
        <property-name name="background" />
        <property-name name="background-color" />
    </handler>
</extension>

<extension point="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.core.elementProvider">
    <provider class="org.eclipse.e4.ui.css.swt.dom.SWTElementProvider">
        <widget class="org.eclipse.swt.widgets.ToolItem" />
        <widget class="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MToolItem" />
        <widget class="org.eclipse.e4.ui.model.application.ui.menu.MHandledToolItem" />
    </provider>
</extension>

/*And css*/
ToolItem:focus {
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
```